# Trigger useEffect hook when only one element in an array change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to trigger the useEffect hook only when a specific element in an array changes.
Right now, I have something similar to this:

```
const [array, setArray] = useState(["someText", "someOthersText"]);
useEffect(()=>{
// some function to run
}, [array[0]])
```

It is working pretty well but I get this warning with my eslint:

> React Hook useEffect has a complex expression in the dependency array. Extract it to a separate variable so it can be statically checked.

It suggests to instead of having "array[0]" put "array" in the dependencies. The problem is that I don't want to have my useEffect triggered when the array[1] changes but only the element at the index 0.

Do you have a solution to avoid this warning and still have it working correctly or it is not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is telling you to do this:

```
const [array, setArray] = useState(["someText", "someOthersText"]);
let item = array[0];
useEffect(()=>{
// some function to run
}, [item]);
```

Comment: I see, indeed it seems that I do not have the warning anymore, but is it not quite "dumb" to do that only to avoid this warning. We are creating a new variable when we could simply call the one in our array. I understand that this is how useEffect works but in terms of readability? 

Anyways thanks for the tips, I would have never thought that.

Comment: @Madere the warning said to *extract it to separate variable*, that is how I guessed. But yeah I don't know why it tells you to do so.

Comment: Keep in mind that changing the array directly will not trigger a render, but the `useEffect` will be called if the value has changed whenever a render is triggered. Even using `setArray` will not trigger a render `setArray(arr => {arr[0] = 'whatever'; return arr})` if you're only modifying the first element and returning the same array.

Comment: it should be `const item = array[0]`